# Pad Navigator program using Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to run a pad navigator project which is already given as example project. While running the program, I am getting the following error. I have no idea about this.

> Error :: :: error: [tmp/rcc/debug_shared/qrc_padnavigator.cpp] Error 1

Can you people give a glance about this?

Comment: That's just a generic error. The actual error message is somewhere above that.

Comment: Thank you Mat. But I am having this only as a error. Have u any idea about this... how to rectify this